# Topological Algorithm is not returning a topologically sorted list

Tags: java, topological-sort

I've implemented a topological sort algorithm that uses DFS in order to construct a topologically sorted list of courses and their pre-reqs. I've implemented it as an adjacency list.

Input:

- 7 courses total.
- Course 1 has prereqs of Course 3
- Course 2 has no prereqs
- Course 3 has prereqs of Course 2
- Course 4 has prereqs of Course 1, Course 2, Course 7
- Course 5 has prereqs of Course 3, Course 1
- Course 6 has prereqs of Course 4
- Course 7 has no prereqs

So I run my topSort algorithm:

```
public static void topSort(Course[] courses){
    int i = 0;
    Course[] solution = new Course[courses.length];
    for (Course c: courses){
        if (!c.visited){
            solution[i] = DFS(c);
        }
        i++;
    }

    for (Course e: solution){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static Course DFS(Course course){
    course.visited = true;
    for (Course pr:course.preReqs){
        if (!pr.visited){
            DFS(pr);
        }
    }
    return course;      
}
```

Output:

```
Course-1
null
null
Course-4
Course-5
Course-6
null
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here. Please advise!

Comment: Why are they static ? is that creating problems ? Can you try by removing the static.

Comment: For one thing, you don't set any value in `solution[i]` if `courses[i]` has already been visited.  Presumably that's where the `null`s are coming from.

Comment: Overall, though, I'm not sure why you think this approach *should* work.  `DFS(c)` always returns `c`, so you cannot achieve a different ordering of the courses this way.  Also, if you want to traverse each subgraph exactly once, as it seems you do, then you must be prepared to receive *several* results from each traversal, not just one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Do you recommend I scrap this implementation and start fresh? Is it that far off what it is I need to do?

Comment: Upon reflection, I think most of the issues could be resolved by fixing `DFS()` so that it returns a `List` of all the vertices traversed, in topological order.  The `topSort()` method would then fill in the result array with all the vertices returned, in the same order as the list.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so essentially having the solution[i] = course in DFS()?

Comment: @TalenKylon, you could probably make it work that way, but I think it would be tricky and messy.  I meant exactly what I said: `DFS()` should return an aggregate containing potentially multiple `Course` objects, in order.  One of the implementations of `java.util.List` would be convenient and appropriate for such an aggregate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I appreciate the suggestion. However, I would like to implement the algorithm as it was intended, and not have to rely on "bandaid" fixes for poor implementation.

Comment: I don't know how you intend to determine how the algorithm "was intended".  Indeed, I presume that if you actually knew that, then you would have implemented it that way in the first place.  Good luck.